# How to Create Calculated field for last 7 days sales

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create one calculated field for last 7 days and want to display same info for like **total order value,Total orders, Total Ordering retailers**
   [image]

**My Formula for Calculated Field**

```
IF ATTR([CreatedDate])>=TOTAL(MAX([CreatedDate]))-6 THEN 
    SUM([OrderAmount])
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new calculated field called [Day Index] that indexes your date field by day:

```
DATEDIFF('day', [Date], today())
```

Then a new field per measure to get the value for the last 7 days:

```
IF [Day Index] <= 6 THEN [Total Orders] END
```

The 6 assures you data source includes the current day also, if it doesn't then you may want to adjust this to 7.

Comment: I just come to know that my above requirement is not possible with tableau, i talk to tableau support regarding same they said that you can't  put two field side by side like i can not view last 7 days just beside of created date, so i have to create other sheet for last 7days part and need to display both sheet in dashboard side by side to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

create calculation :

```
[order Date] >= (TODAY()-7)
```

drag this calculation into filter and select `TRUE`